# Is there anything you can do when a professor discusses some of your personal concerns with other professors potentially mockingly?

Tags: professorship, undergraduate, abuse

I am an undergraduate student. Recently, my interest about a particular (difficult) field – somewhere between physics and maths – arose, a field that is only briefly mentioned in some lectures. For that reason I decided to ask the only professor (Professor A) who could know more about it. Professor A also happens to be a professor that is, in polite words, student-unfriendly. I simply asked if he could suggest some books or topics I could read in order to get prepared for a book that had the whole theory of that difficult field I was looking for.

His first reaction was laughter. He said that even he himself has not “touched” this particular field and that no one else in the whole university could. In the meantime, he used **several provocative phrases** to describe how poorly educated in maths students are for such purposes. It is also known that Professor A generally talks with many students in a bad manner and generally misbehaves. Still, he is a good researcher, and other professors respect him for that (and only that – they know about the misbehaviour).

Anyway, the next thing that happened is that many other professors know about this situation and their behaviour towards me is strange. One of them is a professor I would like to work with (Professor B).
I strongly believe that Professor A said something wrong/different about our conversation.
Right on the day I talked to Professor A, Professor B cancelled (not postponed) a meeting: I went to the meeting and he had already left the building. **I** sent an e-mail saying I came but did not find him. I also included maybe we could meet another time. The reply contained: “I am sorry, but I heard from other professors that you have already discussed the topics you wanted to discuss with me.”

Well, something’s not right.

I definitely can’t ask Professor B directly: “what did Professor A say to you?”. Is there anything I could do? Before contacting anyone else, can I do anything to verify what they had talked about? Or what else could I do?

Comment: Have you spoken directly to the professor who you are interested in working with?

Comment: @Ghost I was about, we arranged a meeting before that situation for other purpose, but he cancelled **-not postponed-** it right on the day the other stuff happened...

Comment: Could have been a very unfortunate coincidence - have you tried to reschedule?

Comment: @Ghost In my e-mail I included that maybe we could meet another time. The reply was something like ok, see ya.

Comment: Now could be an opportunity to write another email - the professor is probably busy.

Comment: @Ghost Still, what could I do about the issue? I think it's not appropriate to ask directly. Gossip about other professors is totally unethical.

Comment: @NickyR: Thanks for your clarifications. I also included your last comment into the question. One last question: Does the field you are talking about happen to be controversial (such as string theory), in particular amongst professors at your university?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft No, it isn't. The topic is just something noone teaches in the university, but many are aware of it. Also, thanks for the editing help. Everything is clearer now.

Comment: What is the field you are referring to? Such behavior by the professor is indeed shocking.

Comment: @yoyostein it really doesn't matter. The professor (A) generally misbehaves, the topic was just a stimulus to do so again. The problem is that he potentially changed some things said and spread it to others...

Comment: _it really doesn't matter_ — No, I think it really _does_ matter; it would be very helpful to know what the conversation was about. @NickyR

Comment: _“I am sorry, but I heard from other professors that you have already discussed the topics you wanted to discuss with me.”_ — So Professor B is a jerk, too.  Maybe you should move to a different department.

Comment: @MadJack Asked for help about books concerning Dirac's and the following theories (I mentioned the specific theories) whilst in the department only Schroendiger is mentioned. Did that really help? What's next?

Comment: @JeffE You really made me laugh! A friend told be the same thing, still professor B is really nice to me, so it's hard to believe that. Isn't that behaviour controversial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I was going to vote to close because you're an undergraduate, but I checked the fine print and I think we're okay here -- this is a situation which could easily occur to a grad student.*

If you still want to talk to the guy who canceled your appointment so rudely, I suppose you could visit his announced office hours and try pretending the whole thing didn't happen

However, if you don't mind being patient, the other approach would be to learn from this experience that your department is a gossip den, and be more circumspect in future; and trust that after some weeks or months, the good guys in your department will realize that you are a serious student worthy of helping.  This approach could be called **taking the moral high ground** and **biding your time**.

Comment: In case I do meet with the professor B within the next days, and something about the issue arises in the conversation, should I continue the discussion or end it politely? Thanks!

Comment: In such a situation, the thing to do is to state the facts calmly, wait a moment, and if there's no response, just move on.  You might want to role-play this with a friend, so it goes more smoothly if this conversation takes place.

Comment: Even if I do, I believe that in such a situation the things I will say to B will seem pretty aggresive. I feel betrayed because, before that B's behaviour was always polite and friendly.

Comment: Well, then perhaps that would push you toward option B, taking the moral high ground.

Comment: "I feel betrayed because, before that B's behaviour was always polite and friendly." I'd suggest at least entertaining the possibility that this may simply be a coincidence that has nothing to do with your conversation with A. B may simply have received some urgent/difficult professional or personal news; think major grant turned down or sudden illness of a loved one. Give it a few days and then reach out again to set up an appointment.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase mentioned at the beginning of OP's question

> It is also known that Professor A generally talks with many students in a bad manner and generally misbehaves. Still, he is a good researcher, and other professors respect him for that (and only that – they know about the misbehaviour).

reminded me of this article:

[How bullying becomes a career tool](https://pure.rug.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/260369120/Tauber_Mahmoudi_2022_How_bullying_becomes_a_career_tool_1_.pdf)

I want to particularly highlight the following excerpts

> People often believe that
> these scientists are bullies despite being
> star academics. Their misbehaviours are
> attributed to an unfortunate decoupling
> between being a good scientist and being
> a decent person. However, academics who
> have experienced bullying often describe
> patterns that suggest a different explanation
> entirely: bullying is a means for mediocre
> scientists to rise to the top.

> “**Abuse of power is not incidental
> to these men’s “greatness”; it is central to it**.”

> The hypercompetitive academic
> environment offers a ‘survival benefit’
> for people with personality traits such
> as **boldness, dominance, meanness and
> disinhibition**.  These personality traits
> have been clearly associated with bullying
> behaviours. This may play out as routinely
> **overstating one’s own achievements but
> belittling those of colleagues**, **planting false
> stories to harm the reputation of colleagues**,
> or **publicly ridiculing, insulting** or tarnishing
> the achievements of colleagues.

Although the post is old, there is no concrete solution for the OP (or every student in similar situation) and no action that they can take by themself. But this article highlights that there should be collective action and awareness f what constitutes bullying behaviour, and bystanders should isolate, report, or reprimand bullies in their working environment.